# Can't access anaconda packages in jupyter notebooks

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

**EDIT:** I found the answer. I had changed my default python to the anaconda version in my PATH, but forgot to do a reboot. After reboot, it worked. Before reboot, the default python was changed in CMD, but not in my IDE or Jupyter.

If I run `CMD` and enter `python`, it returns the defaults python.

```
C:\Users\mjpvanzuijlen>python
Python 3.6.4 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jan 16 2018, 10:22:32) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Here I can import anaconda packages, such as this one.

```
>>> import statsmodels.api as sm
>>> sm
<module 'statsmodels.api' from 'C:\\Users\\mjpvanzuijlen\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\statsmodels\\api.py'>
```

In the jupyter notebook kernell, I can not import any anaconda packages.

I make a new notebook, and chose either the default `Python3` kernel, or the `anaconda` kernel I made. For both options, I'll get the following error.

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-085740203b77> in <module>()
----> 1 import statsmodels.api as sm

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'statsmodels'
```

Running `jupyter kernelspec list` returns the two kernels I have available.

```
C:\Users\mjpvanzuijlen>jupyter kernelspec list
Available kernels:
  python3     c:\users\mjpvanzuijlen\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\resources
  anaconda    c:\users\mjpvanzuijlen\share\jupyter\kernels\anaconda
```

where `...\kernels\anaconda\` holds the following `kernel.json`.

```
{
 "display_name": "anaconda",
 "argv": [
  "python",
  "-m",
  "ipykernel_launcher",
  "-f",
  "{connection_file}"
 ],
 "language": "python"
}
```

**How can I run anaconda packages in jupyter notebooks?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have multiple installations of Python.  You can check which path the Python executable is running on by using

```
import sys
sys.executable
```

A likely culprit is that you have a previous version of Python with Jupyter installed somewhere in `c:\users\mjpvanzuijlen\lib\`.  This by itself is not a big deal, however, you probably also have an entry in your system PATH that has the `jupyter.exe` file from the older Python installation.

Check to see if `c:\users\mjpvanzuijlen\scripts\` is in your system PATH.  If it is, you can remove it from the PATH variable, or you can try to uninstall the previous Python installation.

Answer (score 0):

Im new here so take this as it is:
- Try in terminal `conda env list` to see what environments you actually have. Delete the ones you dont use, or delete both and create a new fresh one
- Try in terminal `conda list` to see what packages conda has installed
- Try updating conda along with all packages `conda update --all`